# Update query that when user clicks on button a value within the table row changes

Tags: javascript, php, database, button, insert-update

I have created a to do list within my site in JavaScript. It is linked to a database within he database table there is "id","content"and "status" The content is the todo item which the suer inputs and the status is a number between 1-3 which indicates the colour the item will turn, this is so the user can see if its done, not done or partially done. At the minute I can change te status value from the database which changes the color, i was hoping to create 3 buttons which the user can click, and this would change the value of the status and therefore change the colour from the front end. 
here are the arrays

```
$res_array = array();
    // fetch all the entires one by one
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        // put query result in php array
        $array = array('id' => $row['id'],
                       'content' => $row['content'],
                       'status'=> $row['status']);
```

Here is the code which makes the item change color

```
$("<li/>", {"id": res[i].id, "text": res[i].content + res[i].status, "class": 'status-' + 
res[i].status}).appendTo(todo.list);
```

All help is appreciated, ps i am new to this, I am guessing it will be an update query

Comment: _“I am guessing it will be an update query”_ – good guess. And now go read up on the necessary basics of the techniques involved to implement it.

Comment: ok well i just wasnt sure